# Which solution/feature contain given Timer Job in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: 2010, timer-jobs

How can I get solution that contain given Timer Job in Sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure is there any direct ways to find this information. Timer Jobs are normally created through a `Feature Receiver`. This receivers are embedded inside assemblies, which is deployed into GAC.

So first find out all features which has a feature assembly

```
Get-SPFeature | Where-Object { $_.ReceiverClass -ne "" }
```

Now look the `ReceiverClass` and see any name is matching with the timer job name.

Next get the solution using `Get-SPSolution`